# How can I check how many pages/blocks are required for storing my table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, storage

Let's suppose we have a table `PEOPLE`. How can I check how many pages/blocks are required for storing it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the actual number of blocks currently used from the system catalog [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

```sql
SELECT oid::regclass AS tbl, relpages
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  relname = 'people'; -- or "PEOPLE"?
```

That's only the main relation. And the count may be somewhat outdated. Not including TOAST, auxiliary relations or indexes. But it includes any amount of bloat, that might be removed with `VACUUM FULL` or similar tools. More:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23933/3684)
- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)

The formulation with `oid::regclass` defends against any confusion with the `search_path`. If the table is not visible (first one in the `search_path`), then the output is schema-qualified.